\texttildelow no longer showing anything
I was using \texttildelow throughout a LaTeX document and now, when compiling in overleaf, it no longer appears. Does anyone know what this might be happening and how it might be fixed?
For example. Here is some code.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a lowered tilde: \texttildelow

\end{document}

When compiled in overleaf I get this:

When compiled in texshop I get this:


When compiling with TeXShop, everything is as normal. Something strange is also happening with my fonts when compiling in overleaf... I wonder if anyone else is experiencing similar?

Show full but minimal example so others can copy the code and test as is. As stated here we have no idea what you are doing, which preamble/setup...

Thanks for your feedback. Please see the adjusted question.

Note that texshop is not related, it is the latex installation used that is important. I have no issue with the code you showed, locally or on Overleaf, I get the same result.

But it does go away when I use xelatx or lualatex. Both of which you have mention nothing. Exactly which engine are you using in TeXShop and on OverLeaf.

How unusual! I'm using a Mac Laptop (Operating system: 14.6.1 (23G93))

That has nothing to do with it, I need to know which latex engine you use in TeXShop and on OverLeaf. My guess is that you use pdflatex in TeXShop and something else on OverLeaf.

I used Pdftex in TeXShop and in overleaf I have XeLaTeX as the compiler. Sorry if this information isn't what you've asked for, these are things I haven't seen before.

That is the important part. If you change xelatex to pdflatex in overleaf it should appear again.

In xelatex and lualatex they attempt to find that symbol in the font (I tihnk under pdflatex it is constructed), but it is not in the font, and so under lualatex we see Missing character: There is no ˷ (U+02F7) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;! in the log. The warning is similar in xelatex.

Thank you so much! That's fixed it!! Amazing :)

I'll write an answer

The MWE works fine if you run it through pdflatex but we get a warning about
Missing character: There is no ˷ (U+02F7) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!

if we use xelatex or lualatex.
The OP was using pdflatex in one place and xelatex in another. Unless one actively looks in the log, you'll only notice that it is missing and not why.
Not sure if there is a package that generates the symbol under xe- or lualatex if it is missing in the font. A more extensive font like stix might have it (untested).

If you run your code with pdflatex you get a low tilde. With xelatex or lualatex the output is font dependent.
You discovered that Latin Modern Roman hasn't the glyph. If you try
This is a lowered tilde: x\texttildelow

with NewComputerModern you get

On the other hand, STIX Two Text will produce

The output with pdflatex and Computer Modern

My guess is that you want none of them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttildelow}{}{%
  \raisebox{-1.3ex}[\dimeval{\height-1.3ex}][0pt]{\kern0.5em\char"0303}%
}
\else
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttildelow}{}{%
  \raisebox{-1.32ex}[\dimeval{\height-1.32ex}][0pt]{\~{}}%
}
\fi

\begin{document}

x\texttildelow x

\end{document}

The amount of shifting might be font dependent.
Output with LuaLaTeX

Output with pdflatex

